# Android Plant App for garden plants and trees

Tags: vegetables

Is anyone aware/use a well built Android app that identifies plants that grow in my area based upon GPS?

Comment: You could start by letting us know what your area is, then maybe continue by saying how the app knows what plant you want to identify.

Comment: You just want to know which vegetables (not plants generally) grow wild in your area? You might try your local extension office if you're in the USA. Although wild vegetables do exist (e.g. amaranth, lambsquarter, Kiwano, tsamma, ground cherries, etc.), unless you live near the Kalajari desert, Brasil, or something, or enjoy eating weeds (many weeds are edible), in most cases, you might be better off just buying some seeds.

Comment: If you're wanting to ID specific plants, you're much better off asking a question than trying to ID with an app. It's incredibly difficult to build an app that accurately IDs plants for any given area, for a variety of reasons—unless that app can do genome sequencing, maybe. But remember, asking for off-site resources is off-topic here (unless it's in the Garden Shed).

Comment: So, to make the question on-topic (and on the queue to be hopefully re-opened), I might recommend changing it to something like this: How can I find out what plants grow wild in my area? If you mean vegetables specifically, you should say so in the question. You can edit your question with the edit link underneath it.